# Is it bad to use the same Topologies/edge loops as reference images?

Tags: topology

Is it alright to try and replicate the topology of other models for making things like faces and bodys? Do I need to think up my own edge loops to avoid plagiarism?

Comment: I've never considered this, it's an interesting question.  The argument could be made that you are reverse-engineering someone's project, I think this argument has been litigated for software.

Comment: This is either opinion based or it may depend on the justice system of your country. So not really suited for this site I'm afraid. As for any other form of art, using references is OK as long as you don't "plagiarise". It may be a gray area though, since topology is rarely in on itself the result of art, but the means to achieve it, and even then you really see it shine mostly when the model animates. If you use multiple references, there shouldn't be any problem.